# Dimension of gradient operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

\begin{align}
y&=Ax\\
z&=f(y)
\end{align}

Then, is it true that:
\begin{align}
\nabla_xz&=\nabla_yf(y)\nabla_xy \\
&=\nabla_yf(y)A
\end{align}

Dimensions:

- $A: m \times n$
- $x: n \times 1$
- $y: m \times 1$
- $z: 1 \times 1$
- $\nabla_yf(y): 1 \times m$?
- $\nabla_xz: 1 \times n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\nabla_xz&=(\nabla_xy)^\text{T}\nabla_yf(y) \\
&=A^\text{T}\nabla_yf(y)
\end{align}

Should clarify things, and get $\nabla_xz$ and $\nabla_yf(y)$ into column vectors.  The dimensions you've listed are right, with the exception of the transposition of the last two vectors.